# Как можно оптимизировать код для перевода из одной системы счисления в другую?

Tags: c++

Код переводит из одной системы счисления в другую,но проверка показывает, что на это тратится слишком много времени.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int Pered(const char* num, int osn)
{

    return static_cast<const int>(strtol(num, NULL, osn));


}
string sys(int b, int n) 
{

    string res = "";

    for (int i = 0; n > 0; i++) {

        if (n == b) {
            res = "10" + res;
            break;
        }

        else {
            if (n % b > 9) {
                res = char('a' + (n % b) - 10) + res;
            }
            else {
                res = char((n % b) + '0') + res;
            }
        }

        n /= b;
    }

    return res;
}
int main()
{
    char num[20];
    int osn_star, osn_new, chis_d;
    cin >> osn_star >>osn_new >> num;
    if (osn_star < 2 || osn_new>36 || num < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    chis_d = Pered(num, osn_star);
    cout << sys(osn_new, chis_d);
}
```

Comment: Есть какие-то ограничения на значения чисел? Только то что помещается в `int`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy особых нет

Comment: Перевод значений в диапазоне `int` или `long` или `long long` и перевод чисел в которых сотни цифр - это две очень разные задачи. Какая вас интересует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так не хотите?

```
int main()
{
    int f, t;
    char n[65] = {0};
    cin >> f >> t >> n;
    _strupr(n);
    unsigned long long m = 0;
    char * c;
    for(c = n; *c; ++c)
        m = m*f + *c - (*c > '9' ? 'A' - 10 : '0');
    for(c = n+64;m;m/=t)
        if ((*--c = m%t + 'A' - 10) < 'A') *c += '0'-'A'+10;

    cout << c;
}
```

Comment: Я не знаю как, но вы волшебник. Мне пока до такого уровня только расти и расти

Comment: Как в каком-то "Ералаше" — "Ерунда, 5 лет тренировки..." :) Самая крутая школа краткости — это был программируемый калькулятор Б3-34...

Comment: @КириллИльиных, учтите, что в приличных местах за такой код можно отхватить канделябром.

Comment: @gbg С этого места подробнее... Где в нем ошибки?

Comment: @Harry в нем нет ошибок, но чтобы это понять, нужно долго и внимательно в него втыкать. 

Код хорошо проверят знание и понимание таких тем как инфиксные операторы инкремента и декремента, приоритеты операций,  работа тернарного оператора и оператора присваивания.

Comment: Также из кода сразу непонятно, какие значения переменных являются граничными для условий в нем, что облегчило бы, например, написание тестов.

Comment: Отладка тоже затруднена, потому что просто навтыкать бряков на разные строчки, не разрушая всю эту красоту невозможно.

Comment: Ну и наличие магических (и взаимосвязанных) констант 65 и 64 наверняка вызовет пристальный интерес статического анализатора.

Comment: @gbg Ну, константа просто исходя из того, что мы работаем с не более чем 64-битным размером, но, конечно, можно было и `sizeof(unsigned long long)*CHAR_BIT`. С остальными замечаниями поспорил бы...

Answer (score 4):

Можно придраться к тому, что строки *уже создаются пустыми и инициализированными*, так что `string res = "";` у вас - просто лишнее.

Теперь, *к реальной проблеме*: Да это же старый знакомый - **[Маляр Шлемиэель](https://nudenoizer.livejournal.com/43431.html)**! [[EN]](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm)

У вас на каждой итерации к строке результату, **спереди**, приклеивается новая цифра числа. Что приводит к необходимости раз за разом копировать в памяти весь предыдущий результат (иногда при этом будет выделяться новая память, что вообще - беда), причем длина копируемого постоянно растет. Это никуда не годится - лучше собрать число задом наперед и один раз перевернуть.

Другие, [более злобные алгоритмы](https://habr.com/ru/post/239375/), используют заранее подготовленные таблицы и SIMD-инструкции, но обычно они заточены на конкретные системы счисления

P.S. Авторство притчи про Шлемиэля приписывается [Джоэлю Спольски](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8,_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BB), который помимо всего прочего, основал и этот сайт в том числе:

> Спольски является сооснователем (совместно с Джефом Этвудом) системы вопросов и ответов Stack Overflow.

Comment: Если уж оптимзировать, то  можно и не переворачивать. Можно передать в функцию указатель на конец nil-terminated буфера (*достаточно большого размера*) для цифр. Класть их в буфер **справа налево** и вернуть указатель на старшую цифру (или знак, если число было отрицательным) / Кстати, сама-то `strtol()` нигде никакую память не выделяет....

Comment: @avp - интересный способ изобрести стек.